# Optimising ST_Intersects query with geometry and point

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I'm trying to optimise the following SQL query, which checks a list of areas to see if the user is within one of them, based on their lat/long. The database is Aurora Postgres, the areas table has one million rows and each query can have up to 50 area ids. On average each polygon has 100 vertices.

```sql
SELECT  id
    FROM    areas
    WHERE   areas.id IN ('1', '2', '3')
    AND     ST_Intersects(areas.geometry, 
                         ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(37.023975, -119.284634), 4326));
```

I'm already using a spatial index (gist (geometry)) on the areas.geometry column.

I've read that it may be beneficial to add the following line before the ST_Intersects:

```
AND areas.geometry && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude, longitude), 4326)
```

Or that calling `ST_SetSRID` within `ST_Intersects` is inefficient and may cause a full table scan, and it should be created outside of the `ST_Intersects` function.

Would either of these changes be effective, or are there any other optimisation I could make

Comment: Which database are you using? and add the `explain` output on your query

Comment: It's not clear from your SQL where `latitude` and `longitude` are coming from. It's also not clear that optimization is necessary. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate the total number of rows in the table, the proportion which has an `id` of 1,2 3 and an indication of the number of vertices in the average polygon. You should also provide the query plan reported by EXPLAIN on the query.

Comment: Without the result of `explain (buffers, analyze)` of your query, there won't be much to optimize... from the question, it sounds more like premature optimization. The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) for `st_intersects` says it is already doing a bounding box comparison, so there is no benefit in re-doing it. You have to set the SRID as functions can't work on mixed SRID.  It is OK as you are doing it because it is applied on constants, so the point creation will most likely occur just once.

Comment: On a side note, you have swapped latitude and longitude (longitude must come first in PostGIS)

Comment: I dont know if this will help your case but when I join and check if points are within polygons it helps alot to [subdivide](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) or create a new table of the intersection of the original polygons and a square grid. And create a new index